# Sending an array to php using retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, retrofit

In my android app, I am fetching some data from using mysql using retrofit 1.9. The data i fetched is in json array. Now i want to use all the values in array in my sql query at once. For example this is my json array i fetch from mysql

```
[{"receivers":"Can23584PtqA"},{"receivers":"New565159nrsN"},{"receivers":"NY H3V9tcig"}]
```

u can it has three values. Values can be 'n'. There is no limit for array length but now i want to send all these again to my sql at once using retrofit 1.9. If i use loop then everytime only 1 value will go to php. Is there any way i can send whole array and use all values in mysql query

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(output);
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {


                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);//returnJson;

                                    String receiver=jsonObject.getString("receivers");// this is the string now i can send it to php but problem is this only one value will be sent at a time. I need all values at same in my sql query



                                            }
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt. Also, does your actual issue have anything to do with PHP and/or mysql?  You should only add tags that are relevant to the issue.

Comment: where do you want to send your data? on server or local sql table?

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(output);
    //list to store list of all receivers
    ArrayList<String> receivers=new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;//returnJson;
        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String receiver=jsonObject.getString("receivers");
            receivers.add(receiver);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //now pass this 'receivers' list to your php server via web api
    //@FormUrlEncoded
    //@POST("index.php?action=item")
    //Call<Receiver> sendReceivers(@Field("items[]") List<String> items);
```

Comment: how will i get the item[] array in php

Comment: can u show me the syntax of getting list array in php parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it again to php you can use JSON or Gson for sending. I recommend to Gson.

For Example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Object> array; // Your array recieved from server it will be object array
String stringarray = gson.toJson(array); //So this is a complete array in single string value you can de-serialize it on both php and android.
```

Please let me know if it is helpful for you